# Flutter convert CashedNetworkImage to Base64 before displaying it

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, base64, networkimageview

Inside my app I am using `CashedNetworkImage` to display my images. The problem is that I need to know what image was loaded and for that I am trying to convert the image after it is loaded to `Base64` so I can compare it with another image.

But I can not make the converting work...

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                  // 1. convert image provider to  base64 String
                  // 2. compare it to sample image
                  // 3. display the image
                },
                imageUrl: widget.memory.imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                progressIndicatorBuilder:
                    (context, url, downloadProgress) => Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: downloadProgress.progress),
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
```

I couldnt find anything on this.. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Ever figure this out?